If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all independent Rademacher random variables, are $XY$ and $YZ$ also independent Rademacher variables?
When I worked it out, I found that it is true, but I am suspicious I made a mistake and am not a statistics expert.
I see that $XY$ and $YZ$ are clearly Rademacher (i.e., they take on values $\{-1,1\}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$), but to prove independence I basically showed that for $a, b \in \{-1,1\}$, that
$$P(XY = a \cap YZ = b) = P\left(X = \frac{a}{Y} \cap Z = \frac{b}{Y}\right) = \frac{1}{4}$$ by the independence of $X, Z$ and since $XY$ and $YZ$ are both Rademacher, this suffices to show $P(XY = a \cap YZ = b) = P(XY=a)P(YZ=b)$.
However, I'm not sure that the step where I divided by the random variable $Y$ is allowed, or if I made a mistake elsewhere.

Since you only have three Rademacher RVs, you could also just enumerate all 8 possible configurations of $X, Y, Z$ and check whether $P(XY)P(YZ) = P(XY \land YZ)$.

Z just flips the sign of both X & Y or doesn't flip either. They're symmetric about 0. The joint distribution of (XZ, YZ) is unchanged from that of the independent (X,Y).

It is just an application of the law of total probability:
\begin{align*}
& P(XY = a, YZ = b) \\
=& P(XY = a, YZ = b, Y = 1) + P(XY = a, YZ = b, Y = -1) \\
=& P(X = a, Z = b, Y = 1) + P(X = -a, Z = -b, Y = -1) \\
=& P(X = a)P(Z = b)P(Y = 1) + P(X = -a)P(Z = -b)P(Y = -1) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2} \\
=& \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}
